# Logout application using NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nstimer, uicontainerview

I have a Login page that segues to the rest of the application.
In the rest of my application the remaining view controllers extend from my own defined 'BaseViewController`.

I am having the following question?

```
 import UIKit

 class BsgBaseViewController: UIViewController {
 var nsTimerObj: NSTimer!
 func resetTimer(addTimeToTimeOutThread: NSTimeInterval){
    nsTimerObj?.invalidate()

    let nsTimerObjTemp = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: "handleIdleEvent:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    nsTimerObj = nsTimerObjTemp

 }


func handleIdleEvent(timer: NSTimer) {

        let createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self
        createAccountErrorAlert.title = ("Title")
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Due to the security policies your session has been timed out. We have to log you out."
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        createAccountErrorAlert.show()

}

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("user touched")
    self.resetTimer(HardCodedValues().hardCodedTimeOutApplication)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.resetTimer(HardCodedValues().hardCodedTimeOutApplication)
    print("appear")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.resetTimer(HardCodedValues().hardCodedTimeOutApplication)
    print("disappear")
}

}
```

1. the method `touchesBegan()` does not get fired when clicking on `UITextField` or `UITextView`.
2. I have a Settings `UIViewController` with a `UISegmentedControl` with two containers and two `UIViewController`. All of these three `UIViewController` derive from my `BaseViewController`. When I click on the other two `UIViewController` three instances of `BaseViewController` get created which I want to avoid.

Comment: Point #2:  What you're seeing is just how derived objects work.  A subclass is an implementation of its parent class...plus some stuff.

Comment: @Phillip Mills what I want to achieve is Logout my application after a certain period of time.

Comment: That's fine.  What I'm saying is that putting the timer logic in a base class that has multiple children doesn't make sense if you only want one timer for the app.  The details of what it does and how it gets reset don't really matter until the structure matches what you need.

Comment: @ Phillip Mills............ I got where I am wrong..............How shall i create  a common NSTimer Object for the whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is to invent an `InactivityMonitor` class and have the app delegate create an instance of that.  Let it own the timer and listen for some kind of "refresh" notification.

View controllers can post those notifications when they get touches so that the timer can reset.

You probably also need your controllers to be delegates for text fields and views so that they can post notifications on that kind of activity too.  In fact, the hardest part may be identifying all the user activity that needs to be noticed, depending on what kinds of UI elements you have.

The other thing I'd want to think about is how your rules should be applied on background/foreground application events.

Comment: Thank you @Phillip Mills ................I added the timer in App Delegate and have got the timer working fine for the tabs too...............Now in each of my UIViewController is there a simple way to know that the user in interacting with the screen..........i tried touchesBegan...............this method however only detects the part of the screen that is empty.........

Comment: In Objective-C you can intercept any event and decide if it should reset the timer.  In Swift, you may have to intercept user actions individually and trigger the reset for each.  Though, see the documentation for `sendEvent:` in `UIApplication`: "*If you require it, you can intercept incoming events by subclassing UIApplication and overriding this method.*"